# How would I go about checking a checkbox when all are checked

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I implemented a functionality, where the user can click on the parent checkbox and all the child checkboxes will be checked. The problem is that when I click on a specific child checkbox, it doesn't uncheck it and just returns true. I need that when all the checkboxes are checked, I can uncheck one checkbox individually and the others remain checked. How can I resolve this?

```
export default function UserList() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, error } = useUsers(page);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [indeterminate, setIndeterminate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
      setUsers(data.users);
    }
  }, [data]);

  function selectUser(e) {
    const selectedId = e.target.value;

    if (ids.includes(selectedId)) {
      const newIds = ids.filter((id) => id !== selectedId);
      setIds(newIds);
    } else {
      const newIds = [...ids];
      newIds.push(selectedId);
      setIds(newIds);
    }
  }

  console.log({ ids });

  function selectAllUsers(e) {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    setIsChecked(e.target.checked);
  }

  function checkedUsers(user) {
    // When unchecked individually, the rest of the checkboxes must be checked.
    return isChecked || ids.includes(user.id);
  }

  console.log(isChecked);

  async function handlePrefetchUser(userId: string) {
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery(
      ['user', userId],
      async () => {
        const response = await api.get(`users/${userId}`);

        return response.data;
      },
      {
        staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 10,
      }
    );
  }

  return (
    <Box>
      <Header />

      <Flex my="6" maxWidth={1480} mx="auto" px="6">
        <Sidebar />

        <Box flex="1" borderRadius={8} bg="gray.800" p="8">
          <Flex mb="8" justify="space-between" align="center">
            <Heading size="lg" fontWeight="normal">
              Alunos
              {!isLoading && isFetching && (
                <Spinner size="sm" color="gray.500" ml="4" />
              )}
            </Heading>

            <HStack spacing={4}>
              <NextLink href="/users/create" passHref>
                <Button as="a" size="sm" fontSize="sm" colorScheme="orange">
                  <Icon as={RiAddLine} fontSize="20" />
                </Button>
              </NextLink>

              <NotificationModal />

              <Button
                as="a"
                size="sm"
                fontSize="sm"
                colorScheme="green"
                cursor="pointer"
              >
                <Icon as={CgImport} />
              </Button>
            </HStack>
          </Flex>

          {isLoading ? (
            <Flex justify="center" align="center">
              <Spinner />
            </Flex>
          ) : error ? (
            <Flex justify="center">
              <Text>Falha ao obter dados dos usuários.</Text>
            </Flex>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Table colorScheme="whiteAlpha">
                <Thead>
                  <Tr>
                    <Th px={['4', '4', '6']} color="gray.300" w="8">
                      <Checkbox
                        colorScheme="orange"
                        onChange={(e) => selectAllUsers(e)}
                      />
                    </Th>

                    <Th>Usuários</Th>
                    <Th>Ações</Th>
                    <Th w="8"></Th>
                  </Tr>
                </Thead>

                <Tbody>
                  {users.map((user) => (
                    <Tr key={user.id}>
                      <Td px={['4', '4', '6']}>
                        <Checkbox
                          colorScheme="orange"
                          value={user.id}
                          onChange={selectUser}
                          isChecked={checkedUsers(user)}
                        />
                      </Td>
```

Comment: Your logic is off; checking the parent checkbox should add the ids of all of the children to `ids` via `setIds`. Right now, once you check the parent checkbox, it changes `isChecked` to true, and JavaScript will never get past that in `checkedUsers`, because `true || anything` is `true`.

Comment: I see, any suggestions to solve it?

Comment: checking the parent checkbox should add the ids of all of the children to `ids` via `setIds`...